# Set breakpoint in gdb on array out of bounds for gfortran program

Tags: fortran, gdb, indexoutofboundsexception, gfortran

I have a Fortran program compiled with `gfortran` with the `-fcheck=bounds` compiler option. This causes the code to report "array out of bounds" errors and subsequently exit.

I would like to debug my program using `gdb` to find the cause of the error. Unfortunately in `gdb` the code will still just exit on an out of bounds error.

Is there a way to tell `gdb` to stop execution when an out of bounds error occurs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compile with `-g` to get debugging information.  Then, first, I placed a break point on `exit`, this works fine, once the program stops you'll be able to backtrace from `exit` to the point of the error.

The backtrace also passes through a function called `_gfortran_runtime_error_at`, so you might have more luck placing the breakpoint there, this worked for me, and obviously will only trigger when you get a run time error.

Comment: In case you're using Intel Fortran, break on `for_emit_diagnostic`

Answer (score 0):

To set a breakpoint on `gdb`, use the command `break` then the name of the file you are debugging, a colon and the number of the line from which you want to break execution :

```
break main.f90:24
```

will stop the execution at line 24 of program `main`. Then you can use the `step` command to jump to the next line and so on. At this point you can use `print` to check the value of any variable you want. If you have defined another breakpoint, you can use the command `next` to jump to the next breakpoint directly.

You will need to compile your program with the `-g` flag to be able tu use `gdb`

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. I know how to set a breakpoint at a specific line of code. I need to break when an "array out of bounds" error is detected. The particular line of code might be evaluated a million times before such an error occurs so setting a breakpoint on that line is not helpful.